# Call WFS request after the map load in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I am trying to call WFS service and store the response in a variable after the map is loaded completely in OpenLayers 3. Below is my code

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: olgm.interaction.defaults(),
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attribution: false,
            zoom:false
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()
        ]),
        target: olMapDiv,
        view: view
    });

this.map.once('postrender', function(event){
        self.test();

    });

this.test = function () {
        self.layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function(extent) {
              $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geowebmap_ws/ows', {
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                  service: 'WFS',
                  version: '1.1.0',
                  request: 'GetFeature',
                  typename:'geowebmap_ws:tn_highways',
                  srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                  outputFormat: 'application/json',
                  bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                }
              }).done(function(response) {
                    self.layerWFS
                    .getSource()
                    .addFeatures(new ol.format.WFS()
                      .readFeatures(response));
                  });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
          })
        });
            mapService.layer_wfs = self.layerWFS;
            console.log(self.layerWFS);
    }
```

Am not getting any WFS features in `self.layerWFS` after the map is loaded. Am I missing anything?

Comment: When you use normally for getting wfs data, can you get data?

Comment: yes i can able to get. When i check in network tab, the request itself is not going to geoserver

Comment: Ok, maybe you should use different event for "postrender", is there any other event for this?